# Ubuntu touch protonmail app

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I was wondering if there is an email push app/scope that supports protonmail for the Ubuntu touch?

I have tried Dekko but they do not have the option to add protonmail.

Comment: Did you try to contact the Dekko and/or Protonmail developers for help?

Comment: I did not. I though maybe someone knew a way to use it in a push/notification way. It is still a kinda new company so i hope there will be a way or app for it in the near future.

Comment: There is the app itself that you can install, which I use myself. As for an email scope, there is not one. I am not too sure how much joy you will get with asking Dekko as it is now not under support any more. That is a shame as Ubuntu Touch needs a multi client email tool, that is good.

Comment: There is a protonmail app for Ubuntu touch? I don't feel joy to contact them, so i will not. But if i am understanding good there is only Dekko as an email client?

Answer (score 2):

In the [OpenStore](https://open-store.io/) there are two unofficial apps for proton mail.

1. [Proton-mail from Jose M Reyes](https://open-store.io/app/proton-mail.josele13)
2. [ProtonMail from Jaume Angrill](https://open-store.io/app/protonmail.txaume)

I don't know if it is safe to use them with your ProtonMail. I asked ProtonMail so if I get an answer I'll post it here.